# WSO2 : RAMPARTUTIL throwing null pointer execption

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, rampart

I have created a web services with RAMPART implementation.

Flow of the Service :
Sender -> Sign Message Using His private key -> Encrypt Message using Server public Key -> sends to Receiver
Receiver -> authenticate message using sender's Public key -> decrypts Message using his private key -> processes the information.

Issue: 
Client is Signing & Encrypting Message  & sent to server
Server is authenticating & decypting the message successfully.
Now, 
post decrypting the message the server processes the values
& has to respond back to client the status.
on return, I am getting following error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [AxisServlet] in context with path [/webService] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.rampart.util.RampartUtil.setKeyIdentifierType(RampartUtil.java:1389)
    org.apache.rampart.builder.BindingBuilder.getSignatureBuilder(BindingBuilder.java:266)
    org.apache.rampart.builder.BindingBuilder.getSignatureBuilder(BindingBuilder.java:250)
    org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.doSignature(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:760)
    org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.doSignBeforeEncrypt(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:417)
    org.apache.rampart.builder.AsymmetricBindingBuilder.build(AsymmetricBindingBuilder.java:88)
    org.apache.rampart.MessageBuilder.build(MessageBuilder.java:147)
    org.apache.rampart.handler.RampartSender.invoke(RampartSender.java:65)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invokeHandler(Phase.java:340)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:313)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:262)
    org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.sendFault(AxisEngine.java:516)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.handleFault(AxisServlet.java:433)
    org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:216)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also, i have implemented the service without RAMPART, in that case the response is successful.

Please advice, I am struggling with from past 2 days..
not able to understand what m i missing since Request decryption is successful, but response is throwing exception.

Answer (score 2):

i added the below block and the error was resolve:

```
<sp:Wss10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
  <wsp:Policy>
    <sp:MustSupportRefKeyIdentifier/>
    <sp:MustSupportRefIssuerSerial/>
  </wsp:Policy>
</sp:Wss10>
```

Comment: thanks for having had this problem more than 3 years ago, i had exactly the same and your solution worked nicely :D